# Producer Consumer in PHP and Java

Tags: java, php, mysql, queue, producer-consumer

I have a system where in I get requests via HTTP call to my PHP code(producer). This code adds the request parameters to a table in MYSQL(queue). This is then taken and processed by a java program(consumer). In my first implementation both producer and consumer was in PHP(with MYSQL queue). Then as load increased this proved inefficient and so I made the consumer java. Now I think polling MYSQL table for the queue from my java app is getting inefficient(vey high cpu usage for MYSQL process). Is there a better way to implement this queue (sharing memory between PHP code and Java app or something)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've got many options. The first is obviously to convert this into a client-server service, and pass either text or binary messages between them. You might want to look into webservices if you're a masochist, or a simpler REST service, or CORBA / COM+ and other for binary serializations. And then there's various queues, like MQseries, RabbitMQ, etc. Sometimes the middle-man is fast enough and efficient enough, or a direct call would suffice.

The next is a more direct link if your platforms are within the same server or cluster, something like [JavaBridge](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/working_with_the_java_bridge.htm) and others (do a search for "java php bridge", and several will crop up. There's even a PHP interpreter written in Java for the JVM which gives you full compatibility between the two which might do the trick for you.